# Multiple column sums in a row

Tags: php

I'm having a problem working out how to create the SUM totals for each column when grouping by the name column. I have tried several different ways but keep getting stuck. I know I have to use the SELECT SUM() but every time I try I keep getting error messages, any help most appreciated.

```
$stats_1013 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `refunds_reports`.`stats_1013` WHERE `date` $thedate");
                    while($stat = mysql_fetch_array($stats_1013)){
                        if($stat['Name'] =="ULTRA TEST 01"){ } else {
                        ?>
                        <tr<?php if($alt_row){ $alt_row = 0; echo ' class="alt-row"'; } else { $alt_row = 1; } ?>>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Connected']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Total Call Duration (sec)']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Average Call Duration (sec)']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Contact Rate %']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Dials']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Avg Dial Duration (sec)']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['No Answer']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Busy']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Failed']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Abandoned %']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Dialler Abandoned']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['User Transfer Attempts']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['User Transfer Connected']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['User Transfer Merged']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Bad Data']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Completed Record']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['DMC']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Recycled Record']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Sale']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Timed Callback']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Answer Machine']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: "I keep getting error messages" what are the error messages?

Comment: so I change the SELECT query to

Comment: $stats_1013 = mysql_query("SELECT `Name`, SUM(`Connected`) AS total FROM `refunds_reports`.`stats_1013` GROUP BY `Name` WHERE `date` $thedate"); and I get the error Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right I've worked it out using the correct mysql

```
    $stats_1013 = mysql_query("SELECT `Name`, COALESCE(SUM(`Connected`),0) AS `ConnectedRow`, COALESCE(SUM(`Total Call Duration (sec)`),0) AS `Total Call Duration (sec)Row`, COALESCE(TRUNCATE(AVG(`Average Call Duration (sec)`),2)) AS `Average Call Duration (sec)Row`, COALESCE(TRUNCATE(AVG(`Contact Rate %`),2)) AS `Contact Rate %Row`, COALESCE(SUM(`Dials`),0) AS `DialsRow`, COALESCE(TRUNCATE(AVG(`Avg Dial Duration (sec)`),2)) AS `Avg Dial Duration (sec)Row`, COALESCE(SUM(`No Answer`),0) AS `No AnswerRow`, COALESCE(SUM(`Busy`),0) AS `BusyRow`, COALESCE(SUM(`Failed`),0) AS `FailedRow`, COALESCE(TRUNCATE(AVG(`Abandoned %`),2)) AS `Abandoned %Row`, COALESCE(SUM(`Dialler Abandoned`),0) AS `Dialler AbandonedRow`, COALESCE(SUM(`User Transfer Attempts`),0) AS `User Transfer AttemptsRow`, COALESCE(SUM(`User Transfer Connected`),0) AS `User Transfer ConnectedRow`, COALESCE(SUM(`User Transfer Merged`),0) AS `User Transfer MergedRow`, COALESCE(SUM(`Bad Data`),0) AS `Bad DataRow`, COALESCE(SUM(`Completed Record`),0) AS `Completed RecordRow`, COALESCE(SUM(`DMC`),0) AS `DMCRow`, COALESCE(SUM(`Recycled Record`),0) AS `Recycled RecordRow`, COALESCE(SUM(`Sale`),0) AS `SaleRow`, COALESCE(SUM(`Timed Callback`),0) AS `Timed CallbackRow`, COALESCE(SUM(`Answer Machine`),0) AS `Answer MachineRow` FROM `refunds_reports`.`stats_1013` WHERE `date` $thedate  GROUP BY `Name`;");
                    while($stat = mysql_fetch_array($stats_1013)){
                        if($stat['Name'] =="ULTRA TEST 01"){ } else {
                        ?>
                        <tr<?php if($alt_row){ $alt_row = 0; echo ' class="alt-row"'; } else { $alt_row = 1; } ?>>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['ConnectedRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Total Call Duration (sec)Row']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Average Call Duration (sec)Row']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Contact Rate %Row']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['DialsRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Avg Dial Duration (sec)Row']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['No AnswerRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['BusyRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['FailedRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Abandoned %Row']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Dialler AbandonedRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['User Transfer AttemptsRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['User Transfer ConnectedRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['User Transfer MergedRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Bad DataRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Completed RecordRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['DMCRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Recycled RecordRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['SaleRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Timed CallbackRow']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $stat['Answer MachineRow']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
```